# Where are all my downvotes gone? long time passing

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, activity-summary

I have an authority problem with my smartphone. It has this thing
about downvoting users without asking for my opinion. So I have to check my
downvotes.  But there is a discrepancy on my activity page. It says
that I have n downvotes, but when I ask for the actual downvotes, to
see what was downvoted, and possibly undo my smartphone initiatives, I
find out that there are only m actual downvotes where m < n.

So, where have all the n-m downvotes gone. Is it downvotes of questions
that were deleted, and thus disappeared, while remaining on my
total count?  The fact is that the same is true for upvotes.

Comment: Once the post is deleted, it won't show up in the votes tab unless you have 10k.

Comment: Perhaps `n` includes down-votes on posts that have subsequently been deleted, where as `m` is just undeleted posts?

Comment: @Mysticial I do have 10k on that account.. But I would like to know what are the posts that were downvoted, even if deleted.

Comment: I take that back. Only close votes and delete votes will show up for 10ks after the post is deleted. Upvotes and downvotes don't.

Comment: So are you proposing a feature request or just discussion? I'm happy with the current way it works since if they showed them all they'd likely not provide a sort option to only show the ones that are still open.

Comment: Well, I first wanted to understand how things work. And I would prefer to be able to retrieve the informtion. But that is very far behing other issues I have with the system as it is. I propose no feature request, but would not protest if this were improved.